# Zoom and pan problems

Tags: javascript, jquery

So i'm attempting to create a script that Zooms in a image, centered at mouse x, y, and with panning.

And it almost works, almost...

When you zoom and pan in the image, it kinda jumps a little, so my math is off, as always.

If u could point me in the right direction it would be awesome, my mind is going numb from trying to subtract different offsets, and it's kinda like a big blur atm !

[**JSBin Example**](https://jsbin.com/hadomerole/edit?html,output)

```
    /**
      MouseDown:   Pan image
      ScrollWheel: Zoom In image
    */

    var $doc = $(".document");
    var scale = 1; 
    var panning = false;
    var start = {x:0, y:0}
    var offset = {left:0, top: 0}

    $(window).bind("mousedown", (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        start = {x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY};
        updateOffset();
        panning = true;
    })
    .bind("mouseup", (e) => {
        updateOffset();
        panning = false;
    })
    .bind("mousemove", (e)=> {

        e.preventDefault();         
        if(!panning) return;
        var x = (e.clientX - start.x) + offset.left;
        var y = (e.clientY - start.y) + offset.top;
        $doc.css({
            "transform": "translate("+ (x) +"px, "+ (y) +"px) scale(" +scale +")"              
        });
    })
    .bind("mousewheel", (e)=>{ 

        e.preventDefault();

        // get scroll direction & set zoom level
        (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta /120 > 0) ?  (scale *= 1.2) : (scale /= 1.2)

        var x = e.clientX - offset.left;
        var y = e.clientY - offset.top;

        var originX = x
        var originY = y

        var translateX = offset.left;
        var translateY =  offset.top;

        $doc.css({
            "transform-origin": originX+ "px " + originY + "px",
            "transform": "translate("+ translateX  +"px, "+ translateY +"px) scale("+scale+")"
        })

        updateOffset();
    });


  // Helpers --------------------------------------------------------


  // graps the transform styles from the element
    function getMatrix($el) {
        if(!$el.css("transform")) {
            return  false;
        }
        var arr = $el.css("transform").match(/\((.*)\)/)[1].split(",");
        return {
            scale: parseInt(arr[0]),
            tx: parseInt(arr[4]),
            ty: parseInt(arr[5])
        }
    }

    function updateOffset () {
        var m = getMatrix($doc)
            offset = {
                top:  m.ty,
                left: m.tx
            };
    }
```

Comment: How do you want it to behave if the mousewheel is used and the mouse position is outside of the image in the blank part of the document area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compensate for the change in scale when calculating the offset:

```
    .bind("mousewheel", (e)=>{ 
        //
        // Zoom
        //
        e.preventDefault();

        // take the scale into account with the offset
        var xs = (e.clientX - offset.left) / scale;
        var ys = (e.clientY - offset.top) / scale;

        // get scroll direction & set zoom level
        (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta /120 > 0) ?  (scale *= 1.2) : (scale /= 1.2)

        // reverse the offset amount with the new scale
        var x = e.clientX - xs * scale;
        var y = e.clientY - ys * scale;
        $doc.css({
            "transform": "translate("+ x  +"px, "+ y +"px) scale("+scale+")"
        })
        updateOffset();          
    });
```

Oh, and you have to use parseFloat instead of parseInt in your getMatrix() call or it just loses accuracy over time!

```
    // graps the transform styles from the element
    function getMatrix($el) {
        if(!$el.css("transform")) {
            return  false;
        }
        var arr = $el.css("transform").match(/\((.*)\)/)[1].split(",");
        return {
            scale: parseFloat(arr[0]),
            tx: parseFloat(arr[4]),
            ty: parseFloat(arr[5])
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks man, I dreamt about this code last night, in a feverish recursive nightmare,  you're a wizard :)